# how to stop the button execution even i exit the form - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day, I'd just like to ask on how to stop button code execution even i exit the form.

my plan is to ask the user to input the authcode before deleting something. this authcode form will show when delete button clicked. this my AuthCodeFrm:...

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtDelAuth.Text == G36_Spare.Properties.Settings.Default.User_DeletePass)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else if (txtDelAuth.Text != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Auth code required");
                
            }
        }

        private void txtDelAuth_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                btnok_Click(sender, e);
        }
```

this is my Deletebtn
[deletebtn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Up0.png)

Comment: Hi, can you be clear, i didn't get exactly, what's your expectation

Comment: Very confusing UI.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Sorry just practicing C# in 3 weeks now :)

Comment: @Romylussone - if pressing that delete button, it will show the authform in which to enter the pw/pin and the delete button will continue to execute if correct pw/pin entered but if cancel/exit button press, the authform supposed to be close and stop the delete code to execute and return to mainform